# How to import a 3d .glft file in three.js

Tags: javascript, html

I wanted to add a .glft file into three.js game. I installed three.js using "npm install three", then I used "npm install three@latest", I used diffrent combinations of import statements, to import a GLFTLoader, for example:

`import { GLTFLoader } from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js';`

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/three@0.126.0/examples/js/loaders/GLTFLoader.js"></script>
```

Nothing works. Here is the html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r126/three.min.js" integrity="sha512-n8IpKWzDnBOcBhRlHirMZOUvEq2bLRMuJGjuVqbzUJwtTsgwOgK5aS0c1JA647XWYfqvXve8k3PtZdzpipFjgg==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/three@0.126.0/examples/js/loaders/GLTFLoader.js"></script>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Game1</title>
        <style>
            body { margin: 0; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="module">

            // initialize the scene, camera, and renderer
            var scene = new THREE.Scene();
            var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
            var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
            renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
            document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

            // create a cube
            var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1);
            var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: 0x00ff00});
            var cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
            var pointLight = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 0.5);
            const size = 100;
            const divisions = 10;

            const gridHelper = new THREE.GridHelper(size, divisions);
            scene.add(gridHelper);
            pointLight.position.set(0, 5, 0);
            scene.add(pointLight);
            scene.add(cube);

            const loader = new GLTFLoader();
            loader.load('/zcar.gltf', function (gltf) {
                const car = gltf.scene;
                car.scale.set(0.5, 0.5, 0.5)
                car.position.set(0, 0, 0);
                scene.add(gltf.scene);
            });

            // set the initial position of the cube
            cube.position.set(0, 0, -5);

            // add event listeners for keyboard input
            var moveDistance = 0.1;
            document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
                switch(event.keyCode) {
                    case 37: // left arrow
                        car.position.x -= moveDistance;
                        break;
                    case 38: // up arrow
                        car.position.z -= moveDistance;
                        break;
                    case 39: // right arrow
                        car.position.x += moveDistance;
                        break;
                    case 40: // down arrow
                        car.position.z += moveDistance;
                        break;
                }
            });

            // render the scene
            function animate() {
                requestAnimationFrame(animate);
                renderer.render(scene, camera);
            }
            animate();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What errors are you seeing? GLTFLoader not defined? Have you tried importing the module locally from node_modules to see if that does the trick?

Comment: I get this error: Uncaught ReferenceError: GLTFLoader is not defined When I import using: "import { GLTFLoader } from "/node_modules/three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js";" I get this error:  "Access to script at 'file:///C:/node_modules/three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, isolated-app, chrome-extension, chrome, https, chrome-untrusted.
index.html:14          GET file:///C:/node_modules/three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js net::ERR_FAILED"

Comment: You are missing a `.` in the front of your URL, as imports usually are relative. You are trying to read this from your root folder on your hard drive - I'm presuming you didn't `npm install` there (don't). Try `import { GLTFLoader } from "./node_modules/three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js";`

Comment: I have this error: "Access to script at 'file:///C:/Users/Antoni%20Nabzdyk/Desktop/Nabzdyk%20Enterprises/New%20folder%20(5)/node_modules/three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, isolated-app, chrome-extension, chrome, https, chrome-untrusted.
GLTFLoader.js:1          Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED"

Comment: Okay, you are trying to run this as file, right? You can't do that, you will need to run a local web server for this to work. The easiest way is to install NodeJS, then in terminal/command prompt run `npm install -g http-server`. Once that is done, navigate to your project root folder in the prompt and run `http-server`. Now your files wil be hosted like they are on a webserver (on `http://localhost:8080`), and your file should run as expected. Why is this happening? The browser doesn't trust sites that try to access the local filesystem and blocks it. It's origin (CORS) is incorrect.

Comment: You can find the docs for the http-server here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server - If you'd rather have a visual interface you could use something like MAMP to host a folder: https://www.mamp.info/en/windows/ - once you have a local server, everything should start working as expected. It's a bit of a hassle but _essential_ for web development, as otherwise you get these CORS ("cross origin resource") error. Your resources are _not allowed to cross 'origin'_ by the browser - namely reach outside it's own server filesystem to fetch files. Good luck!

Comment: This answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/72657255/5535143) shows how to do an import of an additional component. It's importing `OrbitControls.js` but you can swap references and paths to `OrbitControls.js` with `GLTFLoader.js`.

Comment: @DaveB The issue isn't his code ATM, it's how its being served that prevents it from being loaded.

Comment: I get these errors, when I run using the server: Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "three". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".
:8080/favicon.ico:1          Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for chrome-extension://gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom/browser-polyfill.js.map: System error: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Comment: The error is pretty clear right? You need to make sure that you point to a relative path for modules to be resolved. If your main module script is located at root, and root contains node modules, the import is probably something like `import * as THREE from "./node_modules/three/build/three.module.js";`. At least with the server your CORS issues are gone, now you just need to get the pathing right!

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML is using `<script type="module">`. The `three.js` files you're loading are not the module versions. There are two code snippets below. Both will load the `three.js` scene with the single green cube. (Stack Overflow's stack snippets will display a console error. Click on the full page link to see the scene.)

The first code snippet removes `type="module"` and adds the old `new THREE.GLTFLoader()` (versus `new GLTFLoader()` in your original post).

The second code snippet maintains `<script type="module">` and implements the solution in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72657255/5535143). It loads the module versions of `three.js`.

### Without script module

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r126/three.min.js" integrity="sha512-n8IpKWzDnBOcBhRlHirMZOUvEq2bLRMuJGjuVqbzUJwtTsgwOgK5aS0c1JA647XWYfqvXve8k3PtZdzpipFjgg==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/three@0.126.0/examples/js/loaders/GLTFLoader.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Game1</title>
    <style>
        body {
            margin: 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <script>

        // initialize the scene, camera, and renderer
        var scene = new THREE.Scene();
        var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
        var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
        renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
        document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

        // create a cube
        var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1);
        var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({ color: 0x00ff00 });
        var cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
        var pointLight = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 0.5);
        const size = 100;
        const divisions = 10;

        const gridHelper = new THREE.GridHelper(size, divisions);
        scene.add(gridHelper);
        pointLight.position.set(0, 5, 0);
        scene.add(pointLight);
        scene.add(cube);

        const loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();
        loader.load('/zcar.gltf', function (gltf) {
            const car = gltf.scene;
            car.scale.set(0.5, 0.5, 0.5)
            car.position.set(0, 0, 0);
            scene.add(gltf.scene);
        });

        // set the initial position of the cube
        cube.position.set(0, 0, -5);

        // add event listeners for keyboard input
        var moveDistance = 0.1;
        document.addEventListener('keydown', function (event) {
            switch (event.keyCode) {
                case 37: // left arrow
                    car.position.x -= moveDistance;
                    break;
                case 38: // up arrow
                    car.position.z -= moveDistance;
                    break;
                case 39: // right arrow
                    car.position.x += moveDistance;
                    break;
                case 40: // down arrow
                    car.position.z += moveDistance;
                    break;
            }
        });

        // render the scene
        function animate() {
            requestAnimationFrame(animate);
            renderer.render(scene, camera);
        }
        animate();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

### Using modules

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Game1</title>
    <style>
        body {
            margin: 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="importmap">
        {
            "imports": {
                "three": "https://unpkg.com/three@0.126.0/build/three.module.js"
            }
        }
    </script>
    <script type="module">
        import * as THREE from 'three';
        import { GLTFLoader } from 'https://unpkg.com/three@0.126.0/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js';

        // initialize the scene, camera, and renderer
        var scene = new THREE.Scene();
        var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
        var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
        renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
        document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

        // create a cube
        var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1);
        var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({ color: 0x00ff00 });
        var cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
        var pointLight = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 0.5);
        const size = 100;
        const divisions = 10;

        const gridHelper = new THREE.GridHelper(size, divisions);
        scene.add(gridHelper);
        pointLight.position.set(0, 5, 0);
        scene.add(pointLight);
        scene.add(cube);

        const loader = new GLTFLoader();
        loader.load('/zcar.gltf', function (gltf) {
            const car = gltf.scene;
            car.scale.set(0.5, 0.5, 0.5)
            car.position.set(0, 0, 0);
            scene.add(gltf.scene);
        });

        // set the initial position of the cube
        cube.position.set(0, 0, -5);

        // add event listeners for keyboard input
        var moveDistance = 0.1;
        document.addEventListener('keydown', function (event) {
            switch (event.keyCode) {
                case 37: // left arrow
                    car.position.x -= moveDistance;
                    break;
                case 38: // up arrow
                    car.position.z -= moveDistance;
                    break;
                case 39: // right arrow
                    car.position.x += moveDistance;
                    break;
                case 40: // down arrow
                    car.position.z += moveDistance;
                    break;
            }
        });

        // render the scene
        function animate() {
            requestAnimationFrame(animate);
            renderer.render(scene, camera);
        }
        animate();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The car 3d file doesn't show up. I get these errors: "Error: THREE.GLTFLoader: Failed to load buffer "scene.bin".  at Object.onError (GLTFLoader.js:2266:13) at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (three.module.js:34426:40)_onError @ GLTFLoader.js:153
Promise.catch (async)
GLTFParser.parse @ GLTFLoader.js:1993
parse @ GLTFLoader.js:363 (anonymous) @ GLTFLoader.js:173 (anonymous) @ three.module.js:34415 load (async) load @ three.module.js:34393 load @ GLTFLoader.js:169 (anonymous) @ (index):46 three.module.js:39709 GET http://192.168.56.1:8081/textures/BAKE_DISK_baseColor.jpeg 404 (Not Found)

Comment: I used the version with the modules. I get these errors and other errors similar to these.

Comment: The GLTFLoader is now importing so that's good; the first issue listed in your original post has been fixed. Now, the error listed in your comment shows that GLTFLoader is processing your model. The loader encounters a problem trying to load a texture (represented by BAKE_DISK_baseColor.jpeg) referenced in the model file. The loader can't find the `.jpeg` file that is external to the `zcar.gltf` model file. The GLTF loader is trying to load the image file stored in folder `/textures` on root folder.

Comment: What should I do then? I only want to load one 3d file "car.gltf"

Comment: This Discourse post discusses the same issue you're seeing with the missing `/textures` folder: https://discourse.threejs.org/t/how-to-load-gltf-models-with-separate-texture-folder/16531 There is a link to validate your model: https://gltf-viewer.donmccurdy.com/ although you should see the same load errors with the texture files. Do you have any of the texture files that came with the car model file?

Comment: I have the scene.bin and textures folder, but how can I also import them to three.js?

Comment: It works! loader.setPath("/car1/")
        loader.load('car.gltf', function (gltf) {
            car = gltf.scene;
            car.scale.set(0.5, 0.5, 0.5);
            car.position.set(0, 0, 0);
            scene.add(car);
        });